# Making an "input type text" the size of the screen?

Tags: text, input, types, screen

How would I do this?

Just like `<hr/>` but with a text-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is set the Width to 100%

e.g

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<input id="inputBox" style="width:100%;"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 100% is the width of the screen.  Can you explain your question?